# Cart throb and expresso store same install

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, cartthrob

Is it possible to run expresso store and cart throb on the same install for ee 2.9? Both for separate areas of a portal that doesn’t take any payment for orders. It’s used as an internal ordering system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. As you're not using payments you should be fine.